# javascript .push undefined

Tags: javascript, syntax, push

i am using a code bootcamp and have run into a syntax error, i am just having a ton of trouble with that i am willing to bet is so very simple.

```
// this guy here
```

return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);

```
//on this page

const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
  },
  get appetizers() {
    return this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains() {
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts() {
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this._courses_desserts = desserts;
  },

  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };

    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);                      //this is where its located

  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName) {
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[randomIndex];
  },

  generateRandmMeal() {
    const appetizer = getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizer');
    const main = getRandomDishFromCourse('main');
    const dessert = getRandomDishFromCourse('dessert');
    const totalPrice = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    return `your meal is ${appetizer.name}, ${main.name}, ${dessert.name} and your total is ${totalPrice}`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizer', 'wings', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('main', 'bruh', 5.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'dude', 3.00);
```

for the life of me i cant figure out why the syntax .push is saying undefined. ive watched the video over and over and im just not making progress, i could start over from scratch, but i want to understand first why this is happening or i will just not make it in this profession if i can not figure something like this out. thank you

Comment: You are trying to add "appetizer" to a thing called "appetizers" and it's not finding it.  If you look at the definition of getCourses, it tells you what the first parameter of addDishToCourse needs to be (appetizers, mains, desserts).

Answer (score 0):

```
_courses: {
      appetizers:[],
      mains:[],
      desserts:[]
    },
```

appetizers - menu.addDishToCourse('appetizer**s**','wings',4.00);

mains - menu.addDishToCourse('main**s**','bruh',5.00);

Comment: it'd be good to fix your formatting and point out that he's missing the `s` more explicitly (the bold formatting isn't super obvious)

Comment: thank you! i knew it had to be simple enough id overlook it, you ARE the man!